# UITableViewCells in Section0 getting overwritten by cells from section1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 sections. Section 0 gets # of rows after a fetch. Section 1 # of rows are defined to be 2.

Upon getting data for section 0, when I reload the table, the first two cells of section 0 are exactly identical to the two rows of section 1. What gives?

[image]

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSUInteger rows = 0;
    switch (section) {
       case 0:
        rows = self.subscriptions.count;
        break;
    case 1:
        rows = 2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return rows;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]TTEmailPreferencesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TTEmailPreferencesCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

switch (indexPath.section)
{
    case 0:
    {
        TTSubscription *subscription = self.subscriptions[indexPath.row];
        [self configureCell:cell withSubscription:subscription];
        [cell.subscriptionSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(subscriptionSwitchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self configureCell:cell mainTitle:TTNotificationPrefCell1MainTitle descriptionText:TTNotificationPrefCell1Description withSubscription:[self.pushNotificationsDict objectForKey:@"1_pref"]];
            [cell.subscriptionSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(notificationSwitchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            [self configureCell:cell mainTitle:TTNotificationPrefCell2MainTitle descriptionText:TTNotificationPrefCell2Description withSubscription:[self.pushNotificationsDict objectForKey:@"2_pref"]];
            [cell.subscriptionSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(notificationSwitchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}

return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.numberOfRows = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TTEmailPreferencesCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:TTEmailPreferencesCellIdentifier];

 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Save", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(save:)];

self.modified = NO;


__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[[TTAPIManager sharedManager] fetchSubscripWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSArray *subscriptions) {
    weakSelf.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    [self getNotificationPreferences];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //Do something
}];
```

}

Comment: log number of rows before returning at numberOfRowsInSection, isn't it 4 for section 0?

Comment: Put `NSLog()` statements at the beginning of each block (after every `{`) so you can see exactly which path the program is taking. I can't help more since I don't know what `configureCell` does.

Comment: configureCells just configures the 2 labels and switch on/off status.     Here's what I see: When the view gets loaded, since #of rows in Section 1 is 2. I see 2 rows in the view. When I receive response for Section 0 and I do tableview reload, for which I break in cellForRowAtIndexPath for 4 cells for section 0 and two times for section 1 (for which I can already see cells). When the view is entirely loaded, Section 0 first two cells are overwritten. I have also added prepareForReuse in the cell.m file.

Comment: Could you add your viewDidLoad and other relevant lifecycle code to the question? Perhaps it's not a delegate issue

Comment: Added viewDidLoad code

Comment: In addition 8 cells are being instantiated and prepareForReuse is never called.

Comment: In addition, I just found that If I set rows=0 for both sections initially and set them only after I get the data for Section 0, the error goes away. Wondering if anyone else has seen this happening? I am super surprised right now.

Comment: The problem was in the prepareForReuse. I was setting everything to nil. I should have just marked everything as @"" not nil. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be in the prepareForReuse function. 2 of my cells from Section 1 were getting dequeued upon [tableView reloadData] call. The prepareToReuse was setting everything to nil. Setting the labels to empty (@"") and removing the target/action for the switch did the trick.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.nameLabel.text = @"";
    self.descriptionLabel.text = @"";
    [self.subscriptionSwitch removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cell is most likely being dequeued and reused, so the label might be getting cached. Have you overridden `prepareForResuse` to return the cell to a beginning state?

Comment: - (void)prepareForReuse
    {
        [super prepareForReuse];
        self.nameLabel = nil;
        self.descriptionLabel = nil;
        self.subscriptionSwitch = nil;
    }

Comment: Yes, I have added the prepareForReuse fund in the cell.m file.

Comment: im not sure you should be nilling out the controls entirely. reseting the next or returning the switch to the off state would be more likely

Comment: Jpark822: Thanks. this led me to the solution.